# Swift Generic Type Error

Tags: ios, swift, generics, reactive-cocoa

I have a generic type error that's driving me up a wall.

`Cannot convert call result type 'Result<T, NSError>' to expected type 'Result<_, _>'`

I've seen this before when using generics, the compiler complains about `_`.

```
 func test<T: Mappable>(token: Target) -> SignalProducer<T, NSError> {
        let signal: SignalProducer<AnyObject, NSError> = self.request(token).mapJSON()
        let mappedSignal: SignalProducer<T, NSError> = signal.flatMap(FlattenStrategy.Concat, transform: { return SignalProducer(result: self.createMappableFromJSON($0)) })
        return mappedSignal
    }

private func createMappableFromJSON<T: Mappable>(json: AnyObject) -> Result<T, NSError> {
        if let parsedObject: T = Mapper<T>().map(json){
            return .Success(parsedObject)
        }
        let failureReason = "ObjectMapper failed to serialize response."
        let error:NSError = NSError(domain: MoyaErrorDomain, code: 500, userInfo: [NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey: failureReason])

        return .Failure(error)
    }
```

To break it down for you, `test` produces a `SignalProducer` that emits a `Mappable` (ObjectMapper repo) object or an error. So first I map the request to json with `mapJSON` which makes the resulting type `SignalProducer<AnyObject, NSError>`.

Then I do a `flatMap` on that signal, calling `SignalProducer(result: self.createMappableFromJSON($0))` where `$0` is the json object of type `AnyObject` and the return value of the function is `Result<T, NSError>`.
And that's precisely where the above error is throwing, complaining about generic types.

I've done almost anything to try and figure this out. I even went so far as to break the transform closure into a separate variable:

```
let transform:AnyObject -> SignalProducer<T, NSError> = { (value: AnyObject) in
    let result: Result<T, NSError> = self.createMappableFromJSON(value)
    return SignalProducer<T, NSError>(result: result as! Result<T, NSError>)
}
```

but it STILL errors out on the `SignalProducer(result:` line, complaining with the exact same error.

How can I force the compiler to recognize my types correctly?

Comment: Does it work if you remove the `as! Result<T, NSError>`? you don't need that casting since `result` already has that type.